# R use propagate() to calculate the propagated error for summing up a column

Tags: r, montecarlo, propagation

I am learning the `propagate` function and want to use it to calculate the propagated error of summing the raw data in a data frame column. Each row in the data frame is a record, provided with raw data and standard error. A total of one hundred rows (records) are in the data frame. I tried the below code, but it does not work. Can anyone help please!

```
library(propagate)

set.seed(1)    
#create data frame with 100 records with random mean and se
df <- data.frame(raw.data= runif(n=100, min=20, max=100),
                 se = runif(n=100, min=1, max=10))
# set record name, each record is one term in the equation
for (i in 1:100){
  rownames(df)[i]<- paste("x",i, sep="")
}
#transpose to the format required in propagate()
# first row is mean, second row is se
df<-t(df) 

#get the equation
col <- paste (colnames(df), collapse="+") 
EXPR <- expression(col) # so it should be x1+x2+x3+...+x100
RES1 <- propagate(expr = EXPR, data = df, type = "stat", 
                  do.sim = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
```

error message
"Error in propagate(expr = EXPR, data = df, type = "stat", do.sim = TRUE,  :
propagate: variable names of input dataframe and expression do not match!"

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output -- or error messages  --  as well as the desired output.

Comment: I have updated the error message @CarlWitthoft

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with this package, but looking at the documentation, I suspect that your main problem is that the `expr` argument needs variables as inputs, but you are feeding it column names.

The following produces a result...

```
Rgames> x <- df[1,]
Rgames> y <-df[2,]

Rgames> df1 <- cbind(x,y)
Rgames> RES1 <- propagate(expr = expression(x/y), data = df1, type = "stat",do.sim = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
Rgames> RES1
Results from uncertainty propagation:
   Mean.1    Mean.2      sd.1      sd.2      2.5%     97.5% 
10.689918 13.292814  6.926797  8.087914 -2.559210 29.144837 
Results from Monte Carlo simulation:
     Mean        sd    Median       MAD      2.5%     97.5% 
16.153167 15.244058 11.304293  8.550236  2.433047 61.741723
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I also feel like the expression() is a problem. My case is that there are a hundred variables (i.e., x1+x2+x3+...x100). I don't know how to write the expression more efficiently... any thoughts?

Comment: @Elizabeth  I fear that nobody ever anywhere can "propagate" or even do basic ANOVA  when there are a **hundred** independent variables.   You need to take a step back and decide how many of those really matter.   Or better yet, redesign your model.

Comment: hmm, my case is that I have the estimates of the CO2 emissions and standard error of each country in the world, and I want to calculate the global emissions and the propagated uncertainty. So each country is a variable and there are hundreds of variables.  Am I using the wrong model? @CarlWitthoft

Comment: I am "pretty sure" that you want all your 100 means to be a single variable, i.e. a vector with 100 values; ditto for the matching StdDevs.  You would only have 100 **different** variables if you were treating each country separately, which your aren't.

Comment: thank you for this point. If it is just one vector with 100 values, how to calculate the sum and uncertainty? surely the EXPR <- expression(x)  is not correct. Or is there any other model more suitable in this case?